# Configuring BT Home Hub 5 (DSL connection)

Tags: networking, router, openwrt

A friend of mine gave me a BT Home Hub 5 with Open WRT/LEDE (latest) installed on it. I am having trouble getting it configured so it connects to the internet. I am using a DSL broadband connection. My Provider is Sky (UK) and I have captured my IPS username and password. Could anyone point out what I am doing wrong? Please keep in mind that I am beginner.

[image: router's back pannel]
[image]

[image]

**Edit**:

I have managed to get my DSL status to "UP". However, my WAN seems to have trouble connecting to my ISP. This is the router's log:

```
Sat Jan 12 10:01:35 2019 daemon.info pppd[1650]: Plugin rp-pppoe.so loaded.
Sat Jan 12 10:01:35 2019 daemon.info pppd[1650]: RP-PPPoE plugin version 3.8p compiled against pppd 2.4.7
Sat Jan 12 10:01:35 2019 daemon.notice pppd[1650]: pppd 2.4.7 started by root, uid 0
Sat Jan 12 10:01:50 2019 daemon.warn pppd[1650]: Timeout waiting for PADO packets
Sat Jan 12 10:01:50 2019 daemon.err pppd[1650]: Unable to complete PPPoE Discovery
Sat Jan 12 10:01:50 2019 daemon.info pppd[1650]: Exit.
Sat Jan 12 10:01:51 2019 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan' is now down
Sat Jan 12 10:01:51 2019 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan' is disabled
Sat Jan 12 10:01:51 2019 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan' is enabled
Sat Jan 12 10:01:51 2019 daemon.notice netifd: Interface 'wan' is setting up now
```

Comment: Have you been able to configure that unit with your broadband username and password? I have the Plusnet version of that router and I can't change the Plusnet account it's configured for. You need to configure it with your Sky username and password.

Comment: Yes, I have set my WAN with my Sky's username and password and set Protocol to PPPoE. Bit, I have not done the same to my   LAN configuration. Do I have to do the same?

Comment: You have configured DSL as describe on the [OpenWRT page](https://openwrt.org/toh/bt/homehub_v5a)? When you do `dsl_control status` as described on this page, you can see that the DSL is working?

Comment: @dirkt I am afraid that I don't know how to do that on the console, I will have a look at the docs and get back here with the output

Comment: @dirkt Thank you for the instructions. I managed to get my DSL status to UP now. However, my WAN does not seem to connect to my ISP. I have updated my post to include the logs

Comment: Please edit question with output of `dsl_control status`, to verify the DSL interface is not only up, but working properly. You are getting a timeout on initial PPPoE negotiation, which may mean the DSL isn't working properly yet.

Comment: Another thing to check is if Sky UK uses PPPoE at all; googling shows it may use PPPoA or even more funny things like RFC 1483 with MER, though that information may not be current. If you have an ISP modem, does it give any details?

Comment: @dirkt Thanks for the guidance! It appears that Sky is not using PPPeE at all, you were right. It uses PPPoATM. I have managed to get it working by following the steps in Section 9.4 here -> https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c8cqmpc6cacs5n8/AADZ2ZbA162wkeXvimMhVJ7ya/1-OpenWRT-LEDE%20Installation%20Guide%20for%20HH5A%20v1.74b.pdf

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of searching online, I have managed to get this working. It appears that Sky (UK provider) is using PPPoATM (and not PPPoE). Here are the steps:

Network -> Interfaces.

- For the 'WAN' interface, click 'Edit'
- Change the Protocol to PPPiATM, press 'Switch protocol'
  Make sire that the parameters are as shown bellow:
  [image]

Return to Interfaces and go to 'DSL'. Make sure that the parameters are as follows:

[image]

Next, delete the 'ATM Bridge' setting and press 'Save & Apply'.

[Source](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/c8cqmpc6cacs5n8/AADZ2ZbA162wkeXvimMhVJ7ya/1-OpenWRT-LEDE%20Installation%20Guide%20for%20HH5A%20v1.74b.pdf)